# Extract content between tags which is having sub tag

Tags: sed, xml, xmlstarlet

Extract the desired content from the file using "xmlstarlet" or "sed" or "awk" or some similar tool.
The process should refer the full name of the particular businessprocesses and then should just extract content in between that particular business process.

File from where the content to be extracted.

```
 <businessProcesses>
        <fullName>Customer Support</fullName>
        <description>Use for Customer Support, TDG and Port</description>
        <isActive>true</isActive>
        <values>
            <fullName>Action Item</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Solved</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </businessProcesses>
    <businessProcesses>
        <fullName>Customer Support - Port</fullName>
        <description>Telecom team use only</description>
        <isActive>true</isActive>
        <values>
            <fullName>New</fullName>
            <default>true</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Open</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </businessProcesses>
</CustomObject>
```

Required output.

```
<businessProcesses>
        <fullName>Customer Support - Port</fullName>
        <description>Telecom team use only</description>
        <isActive>true</isActive>
        <values>
            <fullName>New</fullName>
            <default>true</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Open</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </businessProcesses>
```

Comment: When you post your homework, you should at least provide enough information to solve the problem and look at basic formatting rules.

Comment: What research have you made to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XML is well formed (the example lacks a `CustomObject` opening tag),

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//businessProcesses[fullName="Customer Support - Port"]' -nl  file.xml
<businessProcesses>
        <fullName>Customer Support - Port</fullName>
        <description>Telecom team use only</description>
        <isActive>true</isActive>
        <values>
            <fullName>New</fullName>
            <default>true</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Open</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </businessProcesses>
```

This uses XMLStarlet with an XPATH query that extracts a copy of the `businessProcesses` node that has a `fullName` child node with the exact value `Customer Support - Port`.

The `-nl` at the end adds a newline to the output.

---

Don't compare XMLStarlet or any other parser of structured document formats  with line-oriented text manipulation tools like `sed`, or `awk`.

Comment: **It is throwing the following error when I tried the above command! **
`file.xml:1.1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
 <businessProcesses>`

Comment: @manojk Your XML document is malformed. I was assuming that you showed us the actual document.  If it has other data in it that is not XML, then this has to be removed first.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output (with an extra space) with

```
awk 'NR==1 || (NR >= 15 && NR <= 26)'
```

or

```
sed -n '1p; 15,26p'
```

If you want a better answer, ask a better question.